# While scrolling jquery iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to accomplish a fixed div on a scroll.  I wrote an if else statement that you can see below:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 

if ($(this).scrollTop() > 296)
{ 
    $('.alphabet').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px', 'left' : '0px', 'z-index' : '9999'});
  } 

});
```

Pretty straight forward and to the point.  This works fine on a desktop browser.  It changes the position of the div from `absolute` to `fixed`.

However, this isn't consistent on iPhone.  Safari mobile does work but only when the user takes their finger off of the screen does the scroll function fire.

The solution is to fire a function while the iPhone is scrolling.  Does anyone know of such a way to do this?  Am I missing something here?